# javaw.exe issue on windows 7

Tags: windows-7, java, process

I have `javaw.exe` process in my task manager. This process takes a lot of processor memory. When I try to close this process my video driver gets closed and Windows 7 repairs it automatically. How to fix this issues?

Comment: Is this behavior continius during the whole work proccess, i mean proccessor memmory load all time while this proccess workin?

Comment: yes it is you are rihgt

Comment: while this process work it load my memmory

Comment: What about antivirus scan? There're lot's of reference that this proccess can be infected, anyway you can find more information about this process here http://www.fileinspect.com/fileinfo/javaw-exe/ but actualy this proccess not virus.